# android ffmpeg set frame-rate

Tags: video, android-ndk, ffmpeg, frame-rate

I am getting a video stream from a camera and I am writing the frames in a file. The problem is that they are being written with a too big frame rate and I can't find a way to set it programmatically.
So I think I am looking for the C function called by the console instruction "-r [framerate]"

I tried setting the option in the avFormatContext but it had no effect.

```
AVDictionary *options=NULL; 
av_dict_set(&options,"r","1",0);
    avio_open2(&oc->pb, "path", AVIO_FLAG_WRITE,options);
```

after that i am reading frames with `av_read_frame(context,&packet)` and writting them with `av_write_frame(oc,&packet);`

Any ideea what I am doing wrong or how should I tackle this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want control the camera frame rate by yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>  
#include <time.h>
...
double ticks; 
int fps=25; //25 FPS for example
uint64_t  frequency;        // ticks per second
double freq,et; 
double mspf=1000.0/(double)fps;

QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER *) &frequency);
freq= (frequency * 1000); 

while(???) {
    ticks=GetTickCount(); // start tick 

    //Read/write function
    av_read_frame(context,&packet);
    av_write_frame(oc,&packet);

    et=(GetTickCount()-ticks)/freq; // elapsed time for current frame, in milliseconds 
    av_usleep((et+1<mspf?mspf-et:1) * 1000);
}
```

Comment: From what I understand 'av_usleep' will only make the thread sleep. This will have no effect on the output video's frame-rate. After returning from sleep the program will still read the following frame from the stream and write it down in the same way.

Comment: Also it is important that I don't skip any frame, as the stream is h264 encoded, and the frames are related (1 key frame + [several inter frames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter_frame))

Comment: The idea here is to get images from the camera slower, so you will not skip any frame and your code will read/write 1 frame every 40 msec