# ffmpeg video streaming deep understanding

Tags: android, video, android-ndk, ffmpeg, streaming

The main question is if it is possible to somehow go around the frame index checking that ffmpeg does when writing the  frame to a file.

Now I will explain my exact problem so you can understand better what I need or maybe think of an alternative solution.

Problem n0.1: I am getting video stream from two independent cameras and for some reason I want to save it in the same video file. First the frames from the first camera and then the frames from the second. When writing the frames from the second camera `av_write_frame` would return the error code -22 and will fail to add the frame. That's because the writing context is expecting a frame index following the index of the previously written frame (the last frame from camera 1) but he receives a frame with the index 0, the first frame from the second camera.

Problem no.2: Consider the following problem independently to the first one.
I am trying to save a video stream to a file but the frame rate is double the real speed. So because I couldn't find any working solution to speed down the frame rate i thought to write every frame twice in the video file. But it won't make any difference to the frame rate.
I also tried a different approach on the frame rate problem but it also failed([question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12963607/android-ffmpeg-set-frame-rate)).

Any kind of working solution would be highly appreciated.

Also it's important that I **can't use console** commands, **I need C code**, as I need to integrate those functionalities in an Android application that is automated.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just change `AVPacket->stream_index` to a consistently incrementing counter on each packet? Another alternative might be using `av_interleaved_write_frame`, but I'm not sure if that would solve the problem.

Comment: As far as I know 'AVPacket.stream_index' is used to know to what stream the packet belongs to, as you may receive more than one stream(audio+video by example). If there would be a way to simply modify the packet index like you thought it would be perfect, but I don't know how is the index retained, actually I don't know if it is being retained at all but that is the only explanation I can find to the problems I'm experiencing.

Comment: I tried 'av_interleaved_write_frame', it makes no difference.

Comment: you should set pts value of each AVPacket to a proper incrementing value